# On the need to use a conditional expectation to calculate a certain expectation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let us define a *parametric statistical model* as a triplet consisting of a probability space $( \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P  )$, a parameter space $\Theta$ (open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$),  and a measurable map

$$     X:  \Omega \times \Theta \rightarrow     \mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^n    \\  \quad   \quad(\omega, \theta) \rightarrow X( \omega, \theta)            $$.

where in $\Theta$ we consider its Borelian sigma-field. Let us define a *statistic* $T: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ as a measurable map. 
Suppose also that the the family of random variables ${X(·, θ), θ ∈ Θ}$ is
also regular in the following sense:

- $X$ has a density $p(·; \theta) \in C^1$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$ with support, $supp(X)$, independent of $\theta$.
- $X(\omega, ·) \in C^1$ as a function of $\theta, \forall \omega \in \Omega$. Furthermore, $\partial_{\theta} X_j \in
  L^2(\Omega)$ and $E(\partial_{\theta} X_j |X = x) \in C^1$ as a function of $x, \forall{\theta} \in \Theta$ and $j = 1, \dots, n$.

Then I find written that

$$       E\left(  \sum_{j=1}^n  \partial_{x_j}  T(X)  \partial_{\theta}   X_j  \right) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{j=1}^n \partial_{x_j} T(x) E[ \partial_{\theta} X_j | X = x ] p(x; \theta) dx  $$

How does one prove this equality?

Also, say that $\partial_{\theta}   X_j$ was a function of $X$ would there be anything wrong in writing $  E\left(  \sum_{j=1}^n  \partial_{x_j}  T(X)  \partial_{\theta}   X_j  \right) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{j=1}^n \partial_{x_j} T(x)  \partial_{\theta} x_j(\theta)  p(x; \theta) dx  $ ?
I am a bit lost on the need for the conditional expectation.

EDIT: An example for $X$ could be $X = (X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$ where $X_j = U_j / \theta$ are iid random variables with $U_j \sim \exp(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the tower law,
$$
\begin{align*}       E\left(  \sum_{j=1}^n  \partial_{x_j}  T(X)  \partial_{\theta}   X_j  \right) &= 
E\left(  E\left( \sum_{j=1}^n  \partial_{x_j}  T(X)  \partial_{\theta}   X_j  \mid X \right)\right)\\
 &= 
E\left(  \sum_{j=1}^n  \partial_{x_j}  T(X)  E\left( \partial_{\theta}   X_j  \mid X \right)\right)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{j=1}^n \partial_{x_j} T(x) E[ \partial_{\theta} X_j | X = x ] p(x; \theta) dx
\end{align*}$$

As you say, if $\partial_\theta X_j$ is a function of $X$ and $\theta$, then the conditional expectation isn't required. I think in normal usage, that would be true, but it isn't actually implied by the assumptions; for example, suppose $\Omega = \mathbb R^{2n}$, and $X_j = \omega_j + \theta \omega_{n+j}$. Then $\partial_\theta X_j = \omega_{n+j}$ is not a function of $X$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you, so concerning your example would we have $E[ \partial_{\theta} X_j | X = x ]= \omega_{n+j}$?  The $x$ vanishes so we are left with a constant we can bring out of the integral?

Comment: @Monolite No, $\omega_{n+j}$ isn't a constant, it's a random variable; remember $\omega \in \Omega$ is a random outcome. So the expectation is taken over the distribution of $\omega_{n+j}$ given $X$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Another thing I was thinking about is that in your example we have $\partial_\theta X_j = \omega_{n+j} = (X_j - \omega_j) / \theta  $ so it seems like $\partial_\theta X_j$ is a function of $X_j$ so we wouldn't need the conditional expectation in this case either, or am I getting something else wrong?

Comment: @Monolite You've shown it's a function of $X_j$, $\theta$, *and* $\omega_j$. But we aren't given $\omega_j$; to avoid the conditional expectation, it needs to be a function of $X$ and $\theta$ *only*.